Error "returns a value referencing data owned by the current function" with traits, etc
I am doing a small project to learn Rust, using geo-types and geo-svg, but I am really stuck with this problem.  I have managed to isolate it with the following code.  It occurs in the last method when returning the result.
The Svg's traits and structs and impl have been trimmed to have a self-contained example, but they are actually in libraries and I cannot change them.
I do not see how the svg value is referencing the point, and how that can be solved.
fn main() {
    let a = Figure { a: 3 };
    println!("result: {}", a.draw().to_svg_str());
}

struct Figure {
    a: i8,
}
pub struct Svg<'a> {
    pub items: Vec<&'a dyn ToSvgStr>,
}

pub trait ToSvg {
    fn to_svg(&self) -> Svg;
}
impl<T: ToSvgStr> ToSvg for T {
    fn to_svg(&self) -> Svg {
        Svg { items: vec![self] }
    }
}

pub trait ToSvgStr {
    fn to_svg_str(&self) -> String;
}
impl<'a> ToSvgStr for Svg<'a> {
    fn to_svg_str(&self) -> String {
        String::from("abc")
    }
}

struct Point {
    p: i8,
}
impl ToSvgStr for Point {
    fn to_svg_str(&self) -> String {
        format!("p = {}", self.p)
    }
}

impl Figure {
    fn point(&self) -> Point {
        Point { p: 3 }
    }
    fn draw(&self) -> Svg {
        let svg = self.point().to_svg();
        svg  // cannot return value referencing temporary value returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
    }
}


"I do not see how the svg value is referencing the point" → self in to_svg has type &Point i.e. is a reference to a point, which… references the Point.

Thanks cafce25, I see your point.  Now... what would be a way to solve it?

Store a Point instead of a &Point or if you must (though dynamic dispatch is usually a code smell) a Box<dyn ToSvgStr>
